# Is there any way to configure the Netsuite default Reconcile Bank Statement form

Tags: netsuite

I wish to configure the Netsuite default Reconcile Bank Statement form so that when user click on Save and Print button it will print the customized Bank Reconciliation report.
However I just found out that there is no customized form available in the default form and hence I am not able to attach any code into it.

Instead of creating a whole new page that mimic and copy the default Reconcile Bank Statement form so that I can add in my code, is there any alternatives for this?
The simplest solution of course is to get user to navigate to the Saved Report > customized Bank Reconciliation report and print from there.
But I just want to see if there is any chance for the user to directly print the customized report after he/she done reconcile the bank statement

Appreciated if you guys can provide any input on this.

Thank you.

[image]